# How to do insecure SSL connection in REST::Client perl

Tags: rest, perl, curl

I'm trying to replicate my curl command to REST::Client api call.

Curl command : `curl -i --insecure -X POST -u username:password https://url`

*Take note of the --insecure*

for some reason, api call should be like that when using curl.

So I have to replicate this using [REST::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client) api call

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried it but from reading [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client) it is possible to use REST::Client with a an existing [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) object. Then this would look something like this:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use REST::Client;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->ssl_opts(SSL_verify_mode => 0); # maybe need verify_hostname => 0 too
REST::Client->new(useragent => $ua)
```

Note that disabling certificate validation using `ssl_opts` can be tricky since depending on the version of LWP::UserAgent used and the patches added by the distribution it will override options from IO::Socket::SSL in an interesting way.

Note also that **disabling certificate validation is a very bad idea in the first place since it makes man in the middle attacks undetectable**. It is instead recommended that you specify the CA used for issuing the servers certificate using [SSL_ca_file](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL#SSL_ca-|-SSL_ca_file-|-SSL_ca_path) and if necessary specify the hostname which should be used for validation with [SSL_verifycn_name](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL#SSL_verifycn_name). Alternatively you can specify the expected certificate with [SSL_fingerprint](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL#SSL_fingerprint).

Answer (score 0):

I've used a badssl.com example which you'll have to update:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use REST::Client;
my $client = REST::Client->new();
$client->getUseragent()->ssl_opts(verify_hostname => 0); # --insecure
$client->getUseragent()->credentials("expired.badssl.com", "", "username", "password"); # -u
$client->POST("https://expired.badssl.com/"); # -X
print $client->responseContent(); # Print the response
```